# In SQL how to get an aggregate over one column of a table and also get a second column adjectant to the aggregate?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't know what the exact terminology to ask this question (will improve the title if somebody can help with that), so will use an example.

For a query `select max(a), b from some_table`, does `b` come from a row where `a` was the maximum value? If not, then is there a way to get it without traversing the table a second time? E.g `select a, b from some_table where a = (select max(a) from some_table) limit 1` would get the correct result but would (as far as I understand) traverse the table twice.

---

### Sample table and result

```
| a | b     |
|---+-------|
| 1 | red   |
| 1 | red   |
| 2 | green |
| 2 | green |
```

Should result in a tuple of:

```
| 2 | green |
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Your (first) query is invalid and expected to raise an error. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You need to `group by b`, the max value is for each distinct value of b but perhaps you are after a windowed max?

Comment: Also note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using sqlite, but you are right, in PostgreSQL it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want one row only, having the max `a` value: `order by a desc limit 1`.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, this does solve my immediate problem! If you posted this as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: I guess there is a wider question still, whether there is a way to have an aggregate over multiple columns, if anyone wants to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a query `select max(a), b from some_table`, does `b` come from a row where `a` was the maximum value?

In this specific case in Sqlite, yes, `b` will be taken from a row whose `a` is equal to the maximum.

From [the "quirks" documentation](https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause) on mixing aggregate and non aggregate values:

> With SQLite (but not any other SQL implementation that we know of) if an aggregate query contains a single `min()` or `max()` function, then the values of columns used in the output are taken from the row where the `min()` or `max()` value was achieved. If two or more rows have the same `min()` or `max()` value, then the columns values will be chosen arbitrarily from one of those rows.

With other databases the query will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row only, having the max `a` value:

```
select *
from tablename
order by a desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> For a query select max(a), b from some_table, does b come from a row where a was the maximum value?

b will be a value from one of the rows that form the group (all rows as there is no GROUP BY clause).

as per:-

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#generation_of_the_set_of_result_rows

> If not, then is there a way to get it without traversing the table a second time? E.g select a, b from `some_table where a = (select max(a) from some_table) limit 1`

Not really, as your example data highlights. i.e. is ***it*** green or green,  or if the data were:-

[image]

Should the ***it*** be green, greenish, blue or blueish? (rhetorical).

If you consider the following:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (a,b);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (1,'red'),(1,'reddish'),(2,'greenish'),(2,'green'),(2,'blue'),(2,'blueish');
SELECT max(a), b FROM some_table;
select a, b from some_table where a = (select max(a) from some_table) limit 1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (a,b);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (2,'blueish'),(1,'red'),(1,'reddish'),(2,'greenish'),(2,'green'),(2,'blue');
SELECT max(a), b FROM some_table;
select a, b from some_table where a = (select max(a) from some_table) limit 1
```

Then the four results (SELECTS) would be:-

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

i.e. your query to get ***it*** produces exactly the same results as the simpler query.

However, the first pair and the second pair of results produce different results. That is due to the query optimiser using the only available index (the **rowid**) and thus that the first inserted (lowest id) is the row from which the arbitrary value is obtained.

Re the commment:-

> I guess there is a wider question still, whether there is a way to have an aggregate over multiple columns, if anyone wants to try that.

Adding

```
SELECT max(a||b),a,b FROM some_table;
```

Results in:-

[image]

Comment: In the specific cases of `max()` and `min()` the non aggregate values will be from the matching max/min row, not an arbitrary one (assuming there's one such matching row). See https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause